# Filtering string array using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to execute the following function, but TypeScript displays the following message:

```
Argument of type '(prev: string[]) => string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.ts(2345)
```

What do I have to change?

```
const [addMore, setAddMore] = useState<string[] | []>(["1"]);

const removeAdd = (value: String) => {
 setAddMore((prev: string[]) => {
   return prev.filter((valueAt: string) => valueAt !== value) as string[];
 });
};
```

Comment: Does this question depend on react or whatever `useState` is from? If so then please tag the question as such. If not, please [edit] to make the code a [mre] that doesn't depend on third party libraries.

Comment: Not in React, it doesn't: https://tsplay.dev/WY5xbW. Note `as string[]` is pointless because the result of `.filter` on a `string[]` is _already_ `string[]`, and I'm really not sure what `| []` is trying to achieve.